# How to include more than one command files

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am working on a discord bot with a huge number of commands,therefore i would like to separate commands into different categories, such as "moderationcommands","musiccommands" etc. However, I am unable to import more than 1 folder of commands. I wish to import commands from a folder called "extras", but I am not sure how to add that into my code. Here is my code importing files from a folder called "commands"

```
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(join(__dirname, "commands", `${file}`));
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.guild) return;

  const prefixRegex = new RegExp(`^(<@!?${client.user.id}>|${escapeRegex(PREFIX)})\\s*`);
  if (!prefixRegex.test(message.content)) return;

  const [, matchedPrefix] = message.content.match(prefixRegex);

  const args = message.content.slice(matchedPrefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  const command =
    client.commands.get(commandName) ||
    client.commands.find((cmd) => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

  if (!command) return;
```

I would appreciate it if someone could suggest a way to import commands from multiple folders

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way I found using [`fs`](https://npmjs.com/package/fs):

```js
// get all folders within the command folder
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./commands'); 
for (const folder of commandFolders) {
 // get all files within each command folder
 const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}`);
 for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${folder}/${file}`);
  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
 }
}
```

Comment: it throws an error: ENOTDIR not a directory , scandir

Comment: And it's the right directory, right? Try `../commands` as well depending on where this file is in your file structure.

Comment: everything seems fine, commands folder is in the folder as index.js , this is the same issue i had when i tried to add other command folders, maybe i should start again?